# Utility class for Android Toast object

Tags: android, toast, utility-method

I have decided to write my own Utility class for Toast to cut repetitive code

```
public class Utilities {

public static void initializeToast(Context context, Toast toast, String res) {
    cancelToast(toast);
    toast = Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

public static void cancelToast(Toast toast){
    if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
    }
}
}
```

As you can see there are two methods. I want to avoid of initializing of stacked toasts, that's way I cancel the old toast before the new one. In my client-classes I'm using it like that:

```
public class AddGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEditWordView;
private Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_group);
    mEditWordView = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.add_group_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditWordView.getText())) {
            Utilities.initializeToast(this, toast, "Message Example");
        }
    });
}
}
```

When I click on button multiple times I'm getting stacked toasts - previous toasts are not being destroyed. So I need a help to define why it behaves in this way.

**UPDATE**
Earlier I wrote the toast-code inside activity class and it worked perfectly. For example:

```
public class AddGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEditWordView;
private Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_group);
    mEditWordView = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.add_group_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditWordView.getText())) {
            initToast("Message");
        }
    });
}

private void cancelToast() {
    if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cancelToast();
}

private void initToast(String res) {
    cancelToast();
    toast = Toast.makeText(this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Write a condition to check if the toast is empty or not and then try canceling it.

Comment: toast.cancel(); and toast.hide(); is not useful to clear all stacked toast.

Comment: you never initialize your `private Toast toast;`. It is always null ,that's why it doesn't cancel anything

Comment: Why not? toast = Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); doesn't initialize?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void initializeToast(Context context, Toast toast, String res) {
    cancelToast(toast);
    if(toast == null){ // prevent create many instance of toast
       toast = Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }else{
       toast.setText(res);
    }
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: I checked your solution. It works a little bit better than mine and solution from previous post, but still not ideal. The idea is that the previous toast must be destroyed after new one appears.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the problem. Thanks to the commentary from Vladyslav Matviienko. My private field was initialized as local variable which was being destroyed after every invocation of the method and that's way cancelToast(toast) didn't bring any effect.

**Utility class**

```
public class Utilities {

public static Toast initializeToast(Context context, Toast toast, String res) {
    cancelToast(toast);
    return Toast.makeText(context, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

public static void cancelToast(Toast toast) {
    if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
    }
}
}
```

**Example of client class**

```
public class AddGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEditWordView;
private Toast toast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_group);
  mEditWordView = findViewById(R.id.editText);
  final Button button = findViewById(R.id.add_group_button);
  button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditWordView.getText())) {
        toast = Utilities.initializeToast(this, toast, "Message Example");
        toast.show();
    }
});
}
}
```